# Drupal 7 webform file field rules attachment

Tags: emails, rules

I have a webform where a user can upload a file; I want this file to be attached to the e-mail using the drupal **rules** module (https://www.drupal.org/project/rules).

I have installed all the required modules (rules, MIME mail, webform, ...)

I configured my HTML e-mail action in drupal rules. When I place a static link inside the attachment body: *sites/default/files/some_file.pdf* it works, but I want this attachment to be dynamic.

Everytime a user submits a file using the webform file field, drupal rules needs to send an e-mail with this file as attachment.

I tried using [data:{component}-value] but it gives me blank field in my e-mail.

How can I do this using the rules module? Not standard built-in attachment function from webform module. Thanks.

Update:

I am trying to use the following information: https://www.drupal.org/node/1431572

How can I combine this with my drupal webform file field? systemname of my field is 'logo'..

Also tried using: sites/default/files/webform/logos/[data:logo-value-html] in the attachment field of rules, but it gives blank email attachments...

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried? If you haven't tried anything, give it a go and then share it here. It will help people answer your question.

Comment: AFAIK thee is no "rule" to add an attachment to an email. I have added attachments to emails successfully and the code can be seen [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2192797)